# Regex pattern for everything untill the next tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Hello again Stackoverflow!

```
<strong>Potato</strong>

preg_match("'<strong>(.*?)</strong>'si", $source, $match);
```

This will return `Potato`, simple regex. But here's the challange. I now have a setup like this that I want to match:

```
<strong>Potato</strong> Carrot
<strong>Apple</strong> Pear
<strong>Lemon</strong> Citron
```

And I would like to have that in an array like so:

```
(
    'Potato' => 'Carrot',
    'Apple' => 'Pear',
    'Lemon' => 'Citron'
)
```

But I have no idea how I could approach this. Could you guys help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
preg_match("'<strong>(.*?)</strong>\s*([^<]*)'si", $source, $match);
```

See [demo](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/19H)

Comment: Thanks! It works, kinda though. What if `Carrot`, `Pear` and `Citron` are links? They don't seem to get parsed now.

Comment: @Thew. If you are dealing with parsing full blown HTML, you should better use an HTML parser instead. You are going to get headache fighting with regex and HTML at the same time. [Time to read this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1679863)

Comment: I'm aware of HTML parsing, but using Simple HTML dom (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) I don't seem to get what I want.

Comment: @Thew. It might be possible, but it will take a lot of effort, which will not be worth at the end. I myself am not much experienced with HTML parsers, so I can't help you with that much.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Either way thanks for the push in the right direction.